# Why won't my Scanner take input when the main method is called by another class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, runnable

My program is supposed to be able to execute java code given a file. However when I try to test it with my test class including a scanner, the scanner doesn't take any input. Right now it only prints, "What is your name?".
What is wrong?

Here is the method for execution:

```
public void execute()
{
    String fileName = file.substring(0, file.indexOf('.'));
    String[] args = null;
    Class c;
    Object o;
    Method main;
    try
    {
        c = Class.forName(fileName);
        o = c.newInstance();
        main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        { 
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    main.invoke(o, (Object)args);
                }
                catch(Exception e){}
            } 
        }
        );
        t.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
```

Here is the code for the test class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name);
        System.out.println("testing");
    }
}
```

Comment: **How** are you running your test class? Does it (in fact) have a connected console?

Comment: *Unrelated:* `main()` is a static method, so your reflection code doesn't need to (and shouldn't) create an instance of the class, i.e. get rid of `o = c.newInstance()`, and simply pass `null` to `invoke()`, as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-): *If the underlying method is `static`, then the specified `obj` argument is ignored. It may be `null`.*

Comment: I run the test class by sending the name of the class to the execute method. The console that it uses is the BlueJ IDE console.

Comment: Try running outside of BlueJ; i.e. compile it using the `javac` command and run it using the `java` command.  My first guess would be that your problem is an oddity with BlueJ's console implementation.

Comment: And fix this abomination!! ..... `catch(Exception e){}` .... which be what is making it hard for you to debug your `execute()` method.

Comment: Thank you. It works when run outside of BlueJ.